# How to continuously improve accuracy of tensorflow object detection model in production flow?

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection

I have already trained an object detection model and got a good prediction accuracy on real images. My question is how to continuously improve the accuracy of the model while using it in production flow.

I can manually check the prediction result, found the wrong predictions, manually label these images, then blend these images with the original training data, continue to train the model. I haven't tried it. But I guess this approach can probably improve the accuracy of the model in the long run. Are there other approaches?

And, if I find several wrong predictions and want to guarantee correct prediction on the same images in a short cycle, what can I do?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You answered it already and that's the way. You would have to retrain the model with more unseen/difficult images that you come across and were not predicted correctly and deploy it in production. To achieve this, save all the input image and predictions so that you can filter them offline and use for retraining